# Problem with any bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth

I have a problem in connecting bluetooth devices. It is weird: I tried with a JETech wireless Optical Mouse and with SONY MDR Headset. I have been using both devices in many different computers and they have always perfectly worked. I used them on windows, mac and linux systems (Debian Jessie).

Recently I bought a new laptop and with this laptop I have not been able to make them work.
The weird thing is that with both devices the same thing happens: the bluetooth sees the device, it pairs with it, the device works for a very short time (maybe a minute) and that’s it. After one minute in bluetooth settings result connected but there is no way of making it work again. If I remove the device from the paired list and pair it again it happens the same (I tried it a thousand times).

My laptop is a Tuxedo InfinityBook PRO
System: Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.13.0-43-generic)

Any help is apreciated

Thanks in advance